# Kivy python *args

Tags: python, function, kivy, args

ive just learn kivy, i dont understand some parameter in the caller in this tutorial :

http://pythonmobile.blogspot.com/2014/06/18-kivy-app-bezier-weight.html

i knew that *arg is the list of object which is passed into the caller. But in this function:

```
class Ex18(BoxLayout):
    def newWeights(self, *args):
        t = args[1]
        self.ids['w0'].value = (1-t)**3
        self.ids['w1'].value = 3*t*(1-t)**2
        self.ids['w2'].value = 3*t**2*(1-t)
        self.ids['w3'].value = t**3
```

What does args[1] mean ?

and this caller in KV language:

```
on_value: root.newWeights(*args)
```

what is the *arg in this caller. which parameters are passed into this, its not explicit. Hope you understand what i mean, my English isn't good. thank so much !

Comment: `*args` is still what you described here: it's a tuple containing the positional arguments given to newWeigts. It seems a bit weird it uses args[1] and discards args[0] though, and it isn't very explicit indeed.

Answer (score 2):

`*args` allows you pass an arbitrary number of arguments to your function, it is the tuple of argument that you pass to the function.

```
def foo(*args):
    for i in args:
        print i
    print type(args)

foo(1, 2, 3,'a')

output:-
>>> 
1
2
3
a
<type 'tuple'>
```

it is used when you actually don't know how many arguments are passed in the function call.

```
print type(args)  #<type 'tuple'>
```

shows you type of `args`

so:-

```
arg[0] = first element of tuple
arg[1] = second element of tuple
.
.
and so on
```

though it is not needed as if you know the nombers argument pass to the function call,

```
def foo(a, b, c, d, e):
    print a, b, c, d, e

foo(1, 2, 'this is','string', [1, 2 ,3, 4])


>>> 
1 2 this is string [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: thank you, but i dont understand this.
    on_value: root.newWeights(*args)
what *args in this.for example, if it calls the function like this:
newWeights(a,b,c), i will understand... but what *args in this.

Comment: @TâmQuangVũ in that document **The slider is responsible for calling the newWeights function, inside the root class** here `*args` carries the arguments for `newWeights` function inside `root`,
I think in `kivy` `on_value` storing the function defination of `newWeights`.

Comment: this means on_value will pass *args newWeights, i don't understand which variable in this tuple. For example, def newWeights(self, *args): t = args[1]. args[1] in this function. i guest it is 'value' variable in the Slider class, but i want to know what is the rule of this. Ive searched in the Kivy doc for several hour but i can't find  it

Comment: Document says you need to call the `newWeight` function with any nomber of arguments, and then it just put some weight(value) to the dictionary keys 'ids' in this case, by the first index value of `arg tuple`.

Comment: i still dont understand it :(. let me explain more clearly my problem.
ive just search on internet, the on_value doenst store newWeights function so i guest the on_value function will call newWeights function as its parameter like this : on_value(newWeights,*args).
In the Slider class have some variable and method, include on_value, value, max, min .... blablabla.in the function newWeights, i guest args[1] is value the class Slider. i dont understand this.. args[1] = value is just my guest. i dont know exactly which is args[1], and what *arg reference to in the function.

Comment: @TâmQuangVũ Why don't you call `newWeight` function with pass somevariable and print arg[1], value and wtever variables are used, rather surfing try to execute and catch the error if any.

Comment: @TâmQuangVũ if you find any help and correct, please mark correct to pramote me. :-)